# how Do i do implement Agile/Scrum in project real?

Tags: agile, scrum

hello I am new here and I am not a software enginner I am a junior only and I saw always this : ** Agile/Scrum** I understand that is but my question is how could I  implement that in a project real like example a system  web/website about a company/etc?

I was looking for a example in google but I look theory only.

someone could show me a example or any way of I could implement this in a project real?

Sorry if my question is in his/her level

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.  Your question might be difficult to answer and I'm not sure if it fits in its current form.  I edited the tags since agile is not a design pattern.  Don't let downvotes and perhaps close flags discourage you; I hope you stick around and I hope to see good question and answers from you in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You may believe you understand what Agile and Scrum mean, but I don't think you really understand them.

I get the feeling that you think Agile and Scrum are something technical, like a design pattern, for which you can find simplified examples to learn from and then you try to apply it to your own code. They are *not*.

Agile is essentially a mindset that talking to people (customers, team members, etc.) and promptly responding to changes is better than trying to write everything down in contracts, documents and ticket systems. Especially for companies that try to minimize their financial risks this is a major change in the required mindset.

As Agile is a mindset, this is also not something you can apply once to a project and then forget about it.

Scrum is one implementation of the Agile ideas and it is aimed at teams of 3 to 10 people. As a junior developer, the best way to really learn about Scrum is to become part of a team where there is an experienced Scrum Master or coach available.
If you are a lone developer, and a junior as well, then you might just as well forget about Scrum for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

[Agile Project Management with Scrum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/073561993X)  was the first book I read on Scrum and I found it very helpful as a developer to understand concretely what Scrum was.

I would also point you toward the [Scrum Guide](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) and the authoritative source for Scrum. As a bonus, it is also both short and free.

Finally, if you are looking at something more code-focused, I would look at some of the [practices in XP](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules.html) like test-driven development, continuous integration, and pair programming.

You mention that much of what you find is theoretical. I want to caution you against assuming things are theoretical. Practices like allowing the teams to set how much work they can do or delivering shippable increments every sprint are meant to be practiced as-written.

Answer (score 1):

There are many starting points to seeing it "for real". Maybe you can find a nearby meetup of developers-of-your-favourite-website-flavour, eg a WordPress meetup or a Drupal meetup. Or, if there are no meetups nearby, maybe there is a user group.

At these meetings, ask some of the other developers if you can sit with them for an hour or two to see how it works.

Because Agile Manifesto item 2:
Working software over comprehensive documentation

Seeing is better than reading.

If you can't speak to and visit a real life scenario, you can watch people on youtube. There's a video of microsoft doing a standup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UUrLxNBK_g.

It depends on what you need. There are many different resources.

Answer (score 1):

Agile and Scrum are actually two different domains, that tend to overlap a lot.

In addition, they are refinements of other software development processes, and lean heavily on a philosophy that supports a particular kind of approach to solving large, often poorly defined, hard to manage problems.

That said, they do not guarantee success, nor do they even prescribe a specific fixed path to use as a template for success.  Rather they prescribe a set of rules and a means of modifying those rules to meet your business needs.  This means that your Agile process will adapt to your company's needs, and will be slightly different than another company's process.

This is why there are checkpoints and values listed in these approaches.  The checkpoints stop the team and (hopefully) make it reflect on the the work done in light of seeing if the values are still being honored.  How does a team do this?  They have some experience developing software, and (hopefully) some experience estimating if their actions uphold the values.

This means that there is not a really good "blueprint" for launching a successful Agile team given no experience in the software field.  My recommendation is to hire a few experienced software developers, who can import some of the background knowledge, with a keen eye on if they seem to value (in your estimation) the values that are promoted by Agile and Scrum.  After all, you can estimate if their values align with the ones published in these methodologies, even if you don't have years of software development experience.

And as for the "for real" part?  I'm guessing you mean "not on paper, but in my company", and the only way to really start doing it "for real" it start doing it (hopefully not too) badly and then improve.

Answer (score -1):

To make your project management theory more "real", launch a Minimum Viable Product (MVP) and then build an Agile/Scrum team around the software development requirements.

For example, you have a PHP, Python, or ASP.Net programmer, a systems administrator for the web server, a front-end specialist for CSS, a graphic designer, mockup artist, & project manager, then setting up various tasks for the team members with benchmarks for completion.

You also need to consider data security, cross-browser testing, performance optimization, & marketing requirements in order to make the project a success.

When you are managing your software product through stages of development, adding innovative features & releasing new alpha/beta versions of an app, the Agile/Scrum organization will grow naturally from the development requirements of the project organically.